# Procedure with an argument of an expression

Tags: c#, linq-expressions

What argument should `SafeRun` has to correctly handle following call scenarios?

```
SafeRun(new SomeClass(arg1, arg2));
SafeRun(new SomeOtherClass());
SafeRun(someObject.FooReturningVoid());
```

I've tried the following but without success :(

```
protected void SafeAct<TResult>(Expression<Func<TResult>> expression)
protected void SafeAct(Expression<Action> expression)
```

`SafeRun` actually does this:

```
protected void SafeAct<TResult>(Expression<Func<TResult>> expression)
{
    try
    {
        Expression.Lambda<Func<TResult>>(expression).Compile()();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ThrownException = e;
    }
}
```

**I do not accept an alternative of calling SafeAct with an lambda expression!**:

```
I DON'T WANT THIS:
SafeRun(() => new SomeClass());
```

Comment: `SafeRun(someObject.FooReturningVoid());` - returning void??

Comment: What I ment with that name is that FooReturningVoid is a function declared like so: `void FooReturningVoid()`

Comment: I thought that. Why would you pass that into another method? It returns void, so as lazyberezovsky mentions below, that can't be done.

Comment: You're missing the point - I want the parameter to be an expression of some kind I execute inside body of `SafeRun` but don't want the user of that function to write a lambda expression, rather write simply body of that expression

Comment: @SOReader If you want to have an expression as a parameter of a method, then the caller of that method has to pass in an expression. There is no way around that.

Comment: @SOReade: there is no way of doing that and it should not be. The compiler will execute and evaluate your code as written. If you want an expression write the correct syntax for an expression. You are asking something in the lines of: i'm writing an "if" statement but i want it to be treated as a "while" statement. Well... write a "while" statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this, because these two calls just return object instance, which cannot be casted to expression

```
SafeRun(new SomeClass(arg1, arg2));
SafeRun(new SomeOtherClass());
```

And passing void is not allowed in C# at all

```
SafeRun(someObject.FooReturningVoid());
```

Take a look on [applicable function member](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691331%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) verification, you'll see that

> A function member is said to be an applicable function member with
>   respect to an argument list A when all of the following are true:
>
> The number of arguments in A is identical to the number of parameters in
>   the function member declaration.
>
> For each argument in A, the parameter
>   passing mode of the argument (that is, value, ref, or out) is
>   identical to the parameter passing mode of the corresponding
>   parameter, and  for a value parameter or a parameter array, an
>   implicit conversion (Section 6.1) exists from the type of the argument
>   to the type of the corresponding parameter

In your case there is no implicit conversion exists from the type of argument (`SomeClass`, `SomeOtherClass`) to parameter's `Expression<Action>` type. Your code will work only if you will define implicit conversions between expression type and types you are passing to method.

Comment: But I want the "parameter" to be interpreted as an expression I execute in the body of `SafeRun` function...

Comment: @SOReader you are not passing expression in first two cases. Both constructors are executed before method call. You are simply passing object instances

Answer (score 1):

For the first call make an interface `ISafeRunable` that exposes a method `void Run()` (kinda like Threads in Java). The prototype should look like this `void SafeRun(IRunable)`.

For the second call make a delegate or just use the Action delegate. The prototype should look like this `void SafeRun(Action actionDelegate)`. And call it like this `SafeRun(someObject.VoidFunction);`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using delegates?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace throw_test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();

            p.Run();
        }

        public delegate void SafeRunDelegate(object sender, EventArgs e);

        public void Run()
        {
            this.SafeRun(this.MyMethodToSafelyRun);
        }

        public void SafeRun(SafeRunDelegate d)
        {
            if (d != null)
                d(this, new EventArgs());
        }

        public void MyMethodToSafelyRun(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, this is just outgrown lambda approach :/ But thanks anyway